# Swap Cases using more than one functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, function, swap

I made Two functions one to convert text to uppercase one to convert to lower case to switch the case of text. This is converting the text but it is not in orderly manner, could anyone help me in this!

```
     function lower(str){
      var output="";
      var small=" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var big=" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<small.length; j++){
          if(str[i]===big[j]){
            output=output+small[j]
          }
        }
      }
      return output;
    }
    function upper(str){
      var output="";
      var small=" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var big=" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<small.length; j++){
          if(str[i]===small[j]){
            output=output+big[j]
          }
        }
.}
      
      return output;
    }


      
      output="";
      var str="PrathamSharma"
      var small=" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var big=" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      for(var i=0; i<small.length; i++){
        for (var j=0; j<str.length; j++){
          if(str[j]==small[i]){
              output=output+upper(str[j]);
          }
          if(str[j]==big[i]) {
            output=output+lower(str[j]);
          }
          
      }
      }
      console.log(output)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code does not work but this should works fine:

```
function lower(str){
      var output="";
      var small=" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var big=" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<small.length; j++){
          if(str[i]===big[j]){
            output=output+small[j]
          }
        }
      }
      return output;
    }
    function upper(str){
      var output="";
      var small=" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var big=" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<small.length; j++){
          if(str[i]===small[j]){
            output=output+big[j]
          }
        }
}
      
      return output;
    }


      
      var output="";
      var str="PrathamSharma"
      var small="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var big="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        for (var j=0; j<small.length; j++){
          if(str[i]===small[j]){
              output=output+upper(str[i]);
          }
          if(str[i]===big[j]) {
            output=output+lower(str[i]);
          }
          
      }
      }
      console.log(output)
```

I just swaped the loop for the str to the outer loop.